# How to include a file relative to an environment variable path

Tags: typescript, include-path

I have an environment variable:

envVar = "c:\myFolder\ManyTypescriptFiles"

How can I include a file in this directory to my current Typescript file ?
Something like this. But this doesn't work.

```
// Include TS files
///<reference path="$(envVar)\targetTypescript.ts"/>

.
.
// Use features of targetTypescript.ts with intellisense support here....
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

In new releases of typescript all ts files in a project are implicitly referencing each other so you do not need to do that probably.

The reference syntax is a bit hacky anyway and i doubt that there is a sane way to do what you want.

If not in the same project then why not use relative paths?
like so: `"../../myfile.ts"`